# Remove last couple of Workdays

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows that include a date from the last two days (today and yesterday).

Column H is the date column.

Here's the relevant bit of the code:

```
Dim lstRow As Long, Idx As Long
lstRow = Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For Idx = lstRow To 2 Step -1 ' change 1 to the first row with dates
    If Cells(Idx, "H") > Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1) Then
        Cells(Idx, "H").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

It doesn't have any effect. The full range of dates (the past 5 days) are still included in the data.

If I reverse the > to <, then ONLY the new dates remain, which is precisely what I want to get rid of.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>=` ?

Comment: BTW, I'd probably assign `Application.WorkDay(Date, -1)` to a long var as well so it doesn't have to be recalculated every cycle.

Comment: If the `>=` didn't take care of the issue, you probably have text that looks like dates. Try `If cdate(Cells(Idx, "H")) >= Application.WorkDay(Date, -1) Then`.

Comment: To clarify: In your question you say any "date from the last two days (today and yesterday," but in the VBA code you're catching any date *after* yesterday (which would include today, but also tomorrow, the next day etc). Is the code supposed to also delete future dates, or does it run on the assumption your worksheet does not include future dates?

Comment: If you have a formula generating the dates, it is possible that the rows are being deleted, but then the dates are regenerated by your formula. If that is the case, inspection might reveal that the last rows are apparently being deleted.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped (and everyone else who chipped in)! It solved the problem immediately, and I incorporated your suggestion on the Long var.

Comment: Posting the solution may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this is the solution that Jeeped proposed and that worked perfectly:

```
Dim lstRow As Long, Idx As Long, wd1 As Long
lstRow = Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
wd1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)
For Idx = lstRow To 2 Step -1 ' change 1 to the first row with dates
    If Cells(Idx, "H") >= wd1 Then
        Cells(Idx, "H").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Having run this code against a sample of dates (from 01/07/2018 to 10/07/2018 [Today]) this code deleted the rows showing today's date. If you want to also delete the previous working day you'd need to change the "-1" to "-2", as below:

```
Dim lstRow As Long, Idx As Long
lstRow = Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For Idx = lstRow To 2 Step -1 ' change 1 to the first row with dates
    If Cells(Idx, "H") > Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -2) Then
        Cells(Idx, "H").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Also, you didn't state it, but as you've used "Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay" it will also delete any dates within that window that are non-work days (so in my sample data the 7th and 8th were also deleted but the 1st was not).